# Bullet list for similar questions on page not found

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, user-interface, 404-not-found

**Page-not-found** would feel good if a bullet list can be used to display **similar questions**.

*Current screen shot:*

> [image]

*Requested change:*

> [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometime during past year, 404 page got a facelift and the **requested change was incorporated**. Here is the current screenshot with similar questions displayed as a bulleted list.

> [image]